# Clasp login fails: "Error retrieving access token..."

Tags: node.js, npm, google-apps-script, clasp

I am trying to set up Clasp on my Windows 10 PC for Google Apps Script. When I try to log in via the command line (`clasp login`), a browser tab opens where I log in to google. After that, the webpage I'm redirected to says the authentication was successful; however the command line shows:

`Error retrieving access token: FetchError: request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate`

**Does anyone know what might be causing this and how I can fix it?**

I don't think this is a network problem as both my raspberry pi and mac authenticated just fine. I have attempted to use `clasp login --no-localhost` to no avail, and changing web browsers doesn't seem to help either. Removing/reinstalling node and npm made no change.

I also disabled my firewall and real-time scanning, nothing.

**What I'm expecting:**

```
C:\Users\User>clasp login

[...]

Authorization successful.

Default credentials saved to: ~/.clasprc.json (/home/pi/.clasprc.json).
```

**What I'm getting:**

```
C:\Users\User>clasp login

[...]

Error retrieving access token: FetchError: request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Comment: Facing the same issue, have we got any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact issue here, but I think this is a generic issue with Google APIs using Node HTTP requests.

Can you try to see if this solution works?

https://github.com/request/request/issues/2061#issuecomment-182573171

Also, I'm more active on the GitHub repo, so consider filing the issue there too:
https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/new

Thanks,
Grant

Comment: Not sure what's missing but it's still not working for me after setting 
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";